# In real life, which remains the most constant: voltage, current or resistance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

According to ohms law,
V=IR, where R is constant

If the resistance of a circuit changes due to change in its physical conditions like temperature, etc.
What will change-current or voltage??

Does the voltage of a battery change with the change in current or resistance???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the circuit design: specifically, there exist [current sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) and [voltage sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source), depending on whether they are designed to sustain constant current or constant voltage, when the load changes.

Specifically, [home power outlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets) are designed as voltage sources - that is regardless of what one plugs in, the voltage (amplitude, since we are talking about ac source) remains approximately the same. E.g., see [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/518480/326735):

> The power outlet on your wall is best approximated as a voltage source, for most of the things you want to do with it, like connect lighting, heating, motor loads to it. Its output impedance is very low. Within the range of current that it is intended to supply, the voltage drop is small.